# C++ error: no matching constructor for initialization of

Tags: c++, constructor, matching

In memberwise assignment in C++, you can set the values of one object to another object of the same class. I initialize a rectangle object with some values and create another rectangle object but assign the value of the first into the second.

It's giving me an error. Why?

Rectangle.h

```
#ifndef RECTANGLE_H
#define RECTANGLE_H

class Rectangle {
    private:
        double length;
        double width;
    public:
        Rectangle(double, double);
        double getLength() const;
        double getWidth() const;
};

Rectangle::Rectangle(double l, double w) {
    length = l;
    width = w;
}

double Rectangle::getWidth() const { return width; }
double Rectangle::getLength() const { return length; }

#endif
```

Rectangle.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rectangle.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Rectangle box1(10.0, 10.0);
    Rectangle box2;

    cout << "box1's width and length: " << box1.getWidth() << ", " << box1.getLength() << endl;
    cout << "box2's width and length: " << box2.getWidth() << ", " << box2.getLength() << endl;

    box2 = box1;

    cout << "box1's width and length: " << box1.getWidth() << ", " << box1.getLength() << endl;
    cout << "box2's width and length: " << box2.getWidth() << ", " << box2.getLength() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Error when I compile:

```
skipper~/Desktop/Programming/Memberwise: g++ rectangle.cpp 
rectangle.cpp:7:12: error: no matching constructor for initialization of
      'Rectangle'
        Rectangle box1(10.0, 10.0);
                  ^    ~~~~~~~~~~
./rectangle.h:4:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor)
      not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
class Rectangle {
  ^
./rectangle.h:4:7: note: candidate constructor
      (the implicit default constructor) not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2
      were provided
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Answers belong in answer posts & not in question posts. Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. [help] [meta] [meta.se]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the line

```
Rectangle box2; // no default constructor, error
```

you are trying to invoke the default constructor of `Rectangle`. The compiler does not generate such a default constructor anymore, because your `Rectangle` has a user defined constructor that takes 2 parameters. Therefore, you need to specify the parameters, like

```
Rectangle box2(0,10);
```

The error I get when compiling your code is:

> Rectangle.cpp:8:15: error: no matching function for call to 'Rectangle::Rectangle()'
>       Rectangle box2;

A solution is to create a default constructor for `Rectangle`, since it is not automatically generated anymore due to your user defined one:

```
Rectangle(); // in Rectangle.h

Rectangle::Rectangle(){} // in Rectangle.cpp (or Rectangle::Rectangle() = default; in C++11)
```

Another solution (and the preferable one, since it doesn't leave the data un-initialized) is to assign default arguments to your existing constructor.

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(double l = 0, double w = 0); // only in Rectangle.h
```

In this way, you make your class Default-Constructible.

Comment: So, from what I understand, whenever I create a user defined constructor, I must also create a default constructor. Was that always the case in C++?

Comment: @skipper Yes. However your user defined constructor can also be a default constructor if you provide default arguments, so there is no need to provide 2 different constructors. A default constructor is any constructor that allows to be called without arguments. For more details take a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor).

Answer (score 4):

A compiler generated default constructor is only generated if you have no defined constructors. You define a constructor, so if you want a default constructor you have to provide it yourself. Probably the easiest (arguably) is to provide it by using default arguments in your two argument constructor:

```
Rectangle(double l=0, double w=0)
```

Also you should use the `inline` keyword as shown below or you may find you get linker errors:

```
inline Rectangle::Rectangle(double l, double w) {
    length = l;
    width = w;
}

inline double Rectangle::getWidth() const { return width; }
inline double Rectangle::getLength() const { return length; }
```

Comment: Shouldn't a default constructor have no arguments?

Comment: @skipper: The default constructor should be called with no arguments. All default parameters satisfies this.

Comment: I wasn't able to make it work by adding the default arguments in rectangle.h. However, I moved the class and member function definitions to rectangle.cpp and it worked fine using default arguments. So, its a solution but not a really satisfying one because I could face the same problem in the future and not have a solution to it.